# Compoent works when added to a View in Interface Builder but not in code

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've been messing with Miguel's port of [MaterialKit](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MaterialSharp).

I'm able to start a new single page project, add a `MaterialButton` to the `View`, change its `Class` to `MaterialButton`, run, and the button functions how it should with its "Material" animations.

If I start an empty project and add the `MaterialButton` in code, it doesn't animate.  Clicking on the button does fire TouchUpInside but in trying to debug [BeginTracking](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MaterialSharp/blob/master/MaterialSharp/MaterialButton.cs#L49) isn't fired.  In the first example, BeginTracking is fired.

Further, if I add a MaterialTextEdit in code, it works fine.  I can't figure out what adding via Interface Builder is doing different that's causing the control to now work when added in code.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;

    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

    float h = 31.0f;
    var w = View.Bounds.Width;

    //This works
    usernameField = new MaterialSharp.MaterialTextField(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 32, w - 20, h))
    {
        Placeholder = "Enter your username",
        BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
    };

    View.AddSubview(usernameField);

    //Seems to mostly work, except for animations
    var bounds = new CGRect (10, 100, w-20, h);
    MaterialButton loginButton = new MaterialButton (bounds);
    loginButton.SetTitle ("Button", UIControlState.Normal);
    loginButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
    loginButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { }; //This works
    View.AddSubview (loginButton);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will make any difference, but you shouldn't set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false unless you're going to add constraints to the button, instead of setting its frame.

Comment: Oops, I was before I made the example.

Comment: "Update:" is not the way SO works, you should answer your own question instead. Downvoting for now.

Comment: I will answer it but I want to make sure the fix is actually the fix as it doesn't specify a button type of custom anymore.  Until then someone else might answer correctly.  Also noted in the PR https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MaterialSharp/pull/2.  I often update my questions answers and see others do the same.  I did note in the update that the change may not be correct.  But down vote away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, [fixed](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MaterialSharp/commit/d58e50364ceb49af427e7556c3e6717d8e16e243) on GitHub now.

```
public MaterialButton (CGRect frame) : base (UIButtonType.Custom)
        {
            Frame = frame;
            SetupLayer ();
        }
```

to

```
public MaterialButton (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
        {
            Frame = frame;
            SetupLayer ();
        }
```